# How do I completely kill a View Controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, view, controller

In my app I am changing views using presentModalViewController, then release the new view controller at the end but somehow it keeps the old view controller active. So is there any way to just completely kill a view controller I am not using?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with presentModalViewController. By using presentModalViewController the new view will be displayed **inside** the original View, just the animation looks like it is above it.

Comment: How would I switch views then with a similar animation while still releasing the old view controller?

Comment: You will need to animate it yourself inside a main ViewController.
It's not that hard.

Comment: So there is no way to kill a view controller. So my only option is to just use addsubview on a main view?

Comment: Kinda, yes. When you release any object (even a view controller) and it's retain count reaches zero, it will be "killed". But that doesn't work for presentModalView because presenting a new VC like that doesn't replace the parent.
You will need to make a "main" viewController and add the views of the different viewControllers to it.

Comment: At this point I think that is going to be too much re-modeling of my app. Is there any way to pause a view then, so that all code in that view stop executing until it is presented modally?

Comment: Just put your code in the viewDidAppear method instead of viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, that will result in the same. There is no way to "pause" the execution of a viewController. :(

Comment: Since Ive never done it before, how would I add my xib's to main centralized view controller?

Comment: Also what about what the other answerer recommended, where I release the view?

Comment: just import the .h files of your viewControllers. Then create instances of them where you need them. You should release them when you don't need them anymore.
e.g. 

`#import "myViewController.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    myViewController *aVC = [[myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myViewController" bundle:nil];

    //Do things with it
    [self.view addSubView: aVC.view];

    //don't need it anymore
    [aVC release];
}`

Comment: If you wan't to store a viewController for a longer period, make an ivar.

Comment: Ok I'm confused. So let's say the parent view is "MainView". Also let's say my original view controller is named "View1". Now how would I add View1 to MainView when a button in "View2" needs to invoke View1?

Comment: write a -displayView1 method in MainView. after you initialized View2 set its parentView = MainView. in the ViewController of view2 handle the button with `[self.parentView displayView1];`
If you want, i could write you a demo project in Xcode 4.1.

I'm not pretty aware of your view hierarchy, can you explain it a bit?
MainView
-View1
-View2
-ViewX

Or is it
MainView
-View2->View1

Comment: That would be fantastic! I don't have a MainView at the moment, but my view hierarchy is like -View1-ViewX (My First view has many different buttons that go to other views.)

Comment: Okay, last question, do the other views (viewX) replace View1 or should that work like a uinavigationbar?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, that i understand your problem, but i've finished the sample project. How should i send it to you?

Comment: send it to: bradychessin19(at)hotmail(.com)
This means a lot to me!

Answer (score 1):

You should release all the views inside the controller as well, this could be your issue.

Comment: So I would do [self.view release]; before my switching views code?